# Reload dataTable after all external data has been recieved

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable, refresh

I can't seem to figure out what is the correct way to reload a datatable. What I am doing is the following:

- Fetching data via ajax for a certain amount of columns
- Creating a table with the retrieved data
- Creating the datatable for that table
- Creating a new ajax request based on the previously fetched data
- Inserting the data in the remaining columns

My objective now is to also be able to sort or perform searches on the new data that has been inserted afterwards. Any ideas on how I should proceed? bDestroy or fnDraw() don't seem to be working for me.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a table with id `mainTable` then you can do this:

```
$("#mainTable").dataTable().fnDestroy();
```

Then you replace the new rows to `mainTable` so you can re-create the `dataTable`:

```
$('#mainTable').dataTable();
```

I'm using this in a project right now and this works for me.

> My objective now is to also be able to sort or perform searches on the new data that has been inserted afterwards.

When you create the table for the second time the `dataTables` should take care of that on it's own.

Comment: Wow, that was so easy.. this is embarrassing :) I thought that a new dataTable instance would lose all my specified parameters I previously defined. Thank you so much for your quick reply!

Comment: No problem, I just faced this recently so I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
oTable.fnDraw();
```

where `oTable` is the variable referencing the dataTable initialization